# \n is not splitting my string to two lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table cell that contains a label like "ThingOne/ThingTwo."

I would like to split the string on the "/" so that it displays as

"ThingOne/

ThingTwo" in the cell.

To that end, I've run the label through a quick replace. label=label.replace('/','/\n'). This works if my window is narrow enough, but if I stretch the window's width out too far, then my cell will display the label as "ThingOne/ ThingTwo" instead of observing the new line character. The width of the cell is a percentage of the screen's width.

Why is the new line character being ignored on a wider table? How can I force the table to split as desired, regardless of the screen's width?

Comment: Hint: HTML doesn't care about newlines, it cares about things like `<br>`.

Comment: Solution: Add a `<br />` and make sure HTML isn't escaped.

Comment: Could you provide some more context please? I noticed the reactjs tag in your post so perhaps we're missing something here. Otherwise it's not the new line you need, but rather <br />